# Django Channels equivalent to reverse()

Tags: django, django-channels

In regular Django, I know I can use [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) to reverse a url.

Is there equivalent functionality in django-channels for reversing a websocket url. If I have the following routing

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "websocket": URLRouter([
        url(r"^foo-websocket/$", FooConsumer, name="foo-example")
    ]),
})
```

Is there something I can call like

```
>>> reverse("foo-example")
"/foo-websocket/"
```

Or is this not possible in django-channels?

Answer (score 3):

For django 3.2.9 i did the following:

```
# in somewhere like "<app>/utils.py"
from django.urls import reverse

def channels_reverse(viewname, args=None, kwargs=None):
    return reverse(viewname, urlconf=PATH_TO_CHANNELS_ROUTING, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
```

where PATH_TO_CHANNELS_ROUING is a stringified path to the file with channels' routings, e.g
`PATH_TO_CHANNELS_ROUTING='sockets.routing'`
Probably, setting.py is a good place to put this variable.

It also requires your routing.py look like:

```
# routing.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/whatever/<str:session_id>/', TheConsumer.as_asgi(), name='control'),
]

websockets = URLRouter(urlpatterns)
```

So now we use regular django's 'reverse' function, that works the following way:

it first imports a variable called `urlpatterns` from file you specified as `urlconf=...` argument in `channels_reverse` function, than just iterates over all `path(...)`s objects in it and finds the one that has name match

Comment: Thanks, this looks good I'll have to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

There are no reverse for channels, but as channels 2 using the same url() format I did following:

1. Created `url_channels.py` file in the app, so in my case it was `chat/url_channels.py` with the following contents:

   ```py
   urlpatterns = [
     url(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>[-\w]+)/$', ChatConsumer, name='chat_endpoint'),
   ]
   ```

   **Note**: you should already have this file, usually it's called `routing.py` and used in `ProtocolTypeRouter` (defined in `mysite/routing.py`), like this:

   ```py
   import chat.urls_channels  # usually routings, but in my case it's urls_channels

   application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
       'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
           URLRouter(
               chat.urls_channels.urlpatterns
           )
       ),
   })
   ```
2. Then in my root/base application created `mysite/urls_channels.py`:

   ```py
   from django.conf.urls import url, include

   urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^channels/', include('chat.urls_channels')),
   ]
   ```
3. Then in `settings.py` added extra URL conf:

   ```py
   ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'
   CHANNELS_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls_channels' # new one
   ```
4. Then in my views I could use standard `reverse_lazy` call, but using channels URL conf instead of default one:

   ```py
   context['chat_endpoint'] = reverse_lazy("chat_endpoint", 
                                           kwargs={'room_name': str(self.object.pk)}, 
                                           urlconf=settings.CHANNELS_URLCONF)
   ```

In this way you have 1 set of patterns for channels which is used for 2 things - in `ProtocolTypeRouter` and for `reverse` call at the same time, keeping things consistent and DRY.

I think also would be convienient to create utility function that would wrap such kind of `reverse_lazy` and append appropriate urlconf automatically, for example call it `channels_reverse_lazy`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. My understanding is that your `reverse_lazy()` call at the end will resolve to `/channels/ws/chat/room_id/`, which isn't actually the url that channels will recognise - as it has the extra `/channels` as the start. Maybe it would be a good idea to create a utility function that removes this.

Comment: hm you are right, missed that but it worked in my case anyway :) I think it's cause I didn't specify "^" in regexp of `chat.urls_channels.urlpatterns`